# 電源供給をせずに、端末をPCに繋いでlogcatでデバッグする方法はありますか？

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, debugging

掲題の通りです。
開発中のandroidアプリについて、電源供給が少なくなった時の挙動を観察したいのですが、端末をusb経由でPCに接続すると、必然的に電源供給がなされてしまい、目的が達成できません。
（アプリの概要：長時間、外部センサーのデータを取得し続けるアプリです。）

ネット上で「データ転送専用usb」と称するものを検索したのですが（二つほど実際に購入しました）、実際に「データ転送」だけを実現できるケーブルが見つかっていません。

何か良い方法がありますでしょうか？
例えば
・実行中の特定のアプリlogcatに出てくるような情報を、オフラインで取得できるような別アプリ
・オフラインでAndroid studioとつないで、logcatとおんなじようなことを行う方法

良い方法がありましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2):

調べたら ""pairing devices using Wifi" というものがありました。

というか、何度も見ていたはずなのですが見逃していました。この機能、素晴らしいです感激しました。